# Load Older Messages from Google Groups Feed

Tags: xml, rss, feed, atom-feed

Is there any way to load older messages from a Google Groups forum, let's say [sf and friends](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/sf-and-friends)?

There are [RSS](https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/sf-and-friends/msgs/rss.xml?num=50) and [Atom](https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/sf-and-friends/msgs/atom.xml?num=50) feeds, but I can only access the most recent 50 messages with them.

I'm asking this because I need to write a script to scrap all messages in a (private) Google Groups forum.  So if there is any other way of doing what I need, it will be appreciated also.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this cannot be done. The API allows retrieving a few more entries but not the whole group, and the HTML is pretty much impossible to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Google still hasn't developed a good api for Groups. [This link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=27) gives a feature request for a Google Groups API but it still has not been taken to development.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as reference, but I think I should keep the bounty because the problem is not solved.  Thank you for your contribution anyways!